# Changing background color of a div on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to change the background color of a div which already has a backkground color that is white for odd element and grey for even element.
Dont know why its not working in Jsfiddle.
The div is also having a ng-click which i have not used in JSfiddle example.
I want to change the color of the div which is clicked to yellow color.
Here is JsFiddle Link....[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhul/HB7LU/17452/)

Basic Code-

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller='Ctrl'>
        <div ng-repeat='item in jsonContacts' ng-style='{"left":($last?lastX:null)+"px","top":($last?lastY:null)+"px"}'>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use  [ngClassOdd](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd)  and [ngClassEven](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClassOdd) : `ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'"` .

and add '**odd**' and '**even**' class to your css file and it should work.

check this upadted version : http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17468/

Edit : I added the change to yellow background

Comment: Thanx for the help...how to make sure that only one element should be yellow...that is clicked,the other should turn into their normal color...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method to control more over your css conditions -

```
ng-style="set_color(item.id)"
```

Please check - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17455/

In **Views** -

```
<div ng-repeat="item in realName" ng-style="set_color(item.id)"  style="cursor:pointer" >
```

In **controllers** -

```
$scope.set_color = function(id) {
    if(id%2 == 0)
        return {"background-color": "white"};
    else
        return {"background-color": "#F0F0F0"};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JsFiddle isn't working because it is using **Angular 1.0.1** and I suspect ternary operator support wasn't implemented in expressions at that stage. This [update JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17454/) only uses a newer version of Angular and your example works as is then.

Also note, `ng-repeat` also has local scope `$even` and `$odd` properties, similar to `$index` that you can use in your calculations, e.g.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
    <div ng-repeat="item in realName" ng-style='{"background-color": ($even?"white":"#F0F0F0")}' style="cursor:pointer" >
        {{item.id}}
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things to note here:

- Your fiddle is using an ancient version of Angular as mentioned by @Beyers
- You can use ng-class-even and ng-class-odd to set odd/even classes dynamically
- The easiest way to change the class on click is to store the active item in a scope variable and then check against it in an ng-class

See a full working fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17462/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!

    <div class="my-div" ng-repeat="item in realName" ng-class-odd="'oddStyle'" ng-class-even="'evenStyle'" ng-click="doChangeBg(item)" ng-class="{'selectedStyle': activeItem === item.id}">
        {{item.id}}
        {{item.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```