# Change styles of an item with ng-click event

Tags: css, angularjs

I need to change the background color of an li tag when I click it.

```
   <ul>
       <li>
          <a ng-click="changeCategory(2)">Category 1</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a ng-click="changeCategory(2)">Category 2</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a ng-click="changeCategory(3)">Category 3</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a ng-click="changeCategory(4)">Category 4</a>
       </li>
   <ul>

   $scope.changeCategory = function(id){

   }
```

And I only need to change **background color witch I click**. It would be great if anyone can look into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing background color of a div on ng-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522270/changing-background-color-of-a-div-on-ng-click)

Comment: There is no accepted answer on that question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**css**

```
.selected {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
   <li ng-class="{'selected': category === 1}">
      <a ng-click="changeCategory(1)">Category 1</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="{'selected': category === 2}">
      <a ng-click="changeCategory(2)">Category 2</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="{'selected': category === 3}">
      <a ng-click="changeCategory(3)">Category 3</a>
   </li>
   <li ng-class="{'selected': category === 4}">
      <a ng-click="changeCategory(4)">Category 4</a>
   </li>
<ul>
```

**javascript**

```
$scope.changeCategory = function(id){
  // other stuff
  $scope.category = id;
}
```

**note**

I changed your first anchor to `changeCategory(1)` rather than `changeCategory(2)`, presuming that was your intention. Also, this is crying out for an `ng-repeat` to satisfy the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.